# Компиляция модуля input-core.ko

Tags: linux, kernel, кросс-компиляция, nas

Компилирую uvcvideo-модуль для поддержки вебкамеры на embedded системе(linux,nas). Модуль скомпилировался, но при insmod ругается:

- uvcvideo: Unknown symbol input_allocate_device (err 0)
- uvcvideo: Unknown symbol input_unregister_device (err 0)
- uvcvideo: Unknown symbol input_free_device (err 0)
- uvcvideo: Unknown symbol input_register_device (err 0)
- uvcvideo: Unknown symbol input_event (err 0)

нагуглил что необходим модуль input-core.ko, но где его включить в menuconfig так и не нашел. Даже при компилировании модулей для поддержки клавиатур, мышей и прочего input, модуль input-core.ko не компилируется.
Подскажите пожалуйста где в menuconfig включить этот модуль.

Update: ядро 3.2.34, модули videodev и v4l2_common инсертятся без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Решено! Нашел конфиг ядра для похожего nas'a, в нем оказалась нужная опция.
Device Drivers  ---> Input device support  --->  Generic input layer (needed for keyboard, mouse, ...)